# Looking For A Better Solution Then An Array List

Tags: java, servlets, dao

Currently I have a working application but I would like some advice because I feel like there must be a better solution. One of the features on the site I am building is a feature to show users videos when they search for them. The search would be done by clicking a link like `"View All Dreamweaver Tutorials"` Each page in the search has a max of 12 videos and if the search has queried more then that you can click a link to go to other pages. Again, all works fine but I am not a fan of my logic and would like to hear if anyone has a better solution to a very common task.

Here's an example of parameters I might send when the user clicks a link ...

```
search?tag=Dreamweaver&sub=CSS&page=1
```

Where `tag` is the main category, `sub` is the sub category, and `page` is the current page they would like to see. If the user gives a page that is out of bounds they are directed to a special screen. So if the servlet saw

```
search?tag=Dreamweaver&sub=CSS&page=1000
```

It would redirect the user!

Now, here's a bit of my servlet that grabs these parameters that are sent ...

```
category = request.getParameter("tag");
subCategory = request.getParameter("sub");
page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));

ArrayList<Integer> startStop = Page.getPageStartStop(page);
int start = startStop.get(0);
int stop = startStop.get(1);

videoList = SearchDAO.getSearchResults(category, subCategory, start, stop);
```

Here is where I do not like my logic. As you can see I first grab the parameters. Fairly normal. But then I call a method in the Page class and send it the page number parameter. So for this example I would be sending the number 1. Then the purpose of that method is to figure out through if statements the start and stop points that the database should query. So that method looks something like this.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getPageStartStop(int page)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> startStop = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if (page == 1)
    {
        startStop.add(0);
        startStop.add(12);
        return startStop;
    }
    else if (page == 2)
    {
        startStop.add(11);
        startStop.add(23);
        return startStop;
    }
        ......
}
```

So for the example if page 1 being sent, the method returns 0 for start and 12 for stop and sends those values to my DAO so that the query knows where to start and where to stop. Below is a snippet of my DAO and the last two questions marks become my start and stop.

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE category = ? AND subCategory = ? LIMIT ?,?");
```

So the problem is that Page class needs a lot of if statements to anticipate pages and return their result. Can anyone else think of a better way to do this. Maybe a common algorithm? So many websites utilize this functionality so I know there must be a cleaner way to carry out this problem. It was honestly just the first thing that jumped into my mind. Thank you so much for reading! Comments and answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));` Is going to throw an exception if `page` is missing.  You probably want to default to the first page or something, so maybe: `page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page") != null ? request.getParameter("page") : "0");`

Comment: They never get to that part of the code if page is missing. An error check is performed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do something like this

```
private static int ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 10;

public static List<Integer> getPageStartStop(int page) {
    int start = ITEMS_PER_PAGE * (page-1); // will return 0 for page 1, 10 for page 2, etc...
    int stop = (ITEMS_PER_PAGE * page) + 1; // will return 11 for page 1, 21 for page 2, etc...

    return Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { start, stop });
}
```

And indeed, this is called pagination.

Comment: if page is anything other then 1 this does not work. If it was 2 the start would be 12 * 2 so 24. The correct answer however should be 11.

Comment: Ah, well, I assumed you'd be starting at page 0 :). If your pages start at 1, you could use `ITEMS_PER_PAGE * (page - 1)` and `(ITEMS_PER_PAGE - 1) + (ITEMS_PER_PAGE * (page - 1))`.

Comment: @gmustudent if you look at the pages as "first page is 0", "second page is 1" and "third page is 2", then this works perfectly. It genrates "0-11", "12-23", "24-35". If you want to treat as "first page is 1", "second page is 2", "third page is 3", then just replace page with "page-1" in the above solution.

Comment: That's the problem, it should generate (0,11) (11,23) (22,34) (33,45)

Comment: @gmustudent what...? it should generate 11 as both start of the page 2 and end of page one, but on the next page, it would be 23 and 22? it makes no sense.... even your example in the question does not follow that logic.

Comment: Are you saying the second page should start with 11 while the first page should end with 12? In other words, items 11 and 12 appear on both the first *and* the second page?

Comment: I'm very sorry guys. I got confused. Okay 10 results should be show per page. However the database will show the correct values if the pattern is (0,11) (10,21) (20,31)

Comment: Check the updated code. It'll now return (0-11) for page 1, (10-21) for page 2, (20-31) for page 3.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to hardcode your page start stop indexes in array. Think what happens when you decide to show more elements on the page.

Use `firstResult` and `maxResults` where `firstResult` is your page number and `maxResults` is maximum number of items on a single page. Then you can do `firstResult * maxResults`.

For example see http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/pagination-in-hibernate-with-criteria-api.

Comment: Can you explain, I don't fully understand the harm. Thank you.

Comment: If your element numbers are hardcoded in your code then you need to change it every time you want to change how many elements you are showing on one page.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getPageStartStop(int page)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> startStop = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int NoOfItems = 12;
    if (page > 0 && page < 1000)
    {
        startStop.add(page*NoOfItems - NoOfItems);//will return 0 for page 1
        startStop.add(page*NoOfItems);//will return 12 for page 1
        return startStop;
    }else{
            //your logic if page number exceeds than your set limit or it is less than 1
    }

}
```

Comment: why start will be (2*12 -12)=12 and stop will be (2*12)=24